# OpenCart Theme installation permission issue

Tags: opencart

I installed OpenCart in my hosting account, now I am trying to install the theme, but it keeps telling me this error when I upload it:

"The directory system/custom.ocmod.xml is not allowed to be written to[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qthSl.png)"

How do i fix this?

Also In the installation documentary it says I should install "no_FTP.ocmod.XML" but it also says "Invalid file type".

Comment: You need to upload a xxx.ocmod.zip file - You can no longer upload an xxx.ocmod.xml file without it being in a zip archive.

Comment: I am doing that also! uploading the theme as ocmod.zip but nothing works.

Comment: please check here for more information of this issue - https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/5572

Comment: You can use this extension and your problem will be resolved: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&member_token=b16a48325d9b168e41854096f1e35e4a&extension_id=37848
But is it not recommended. Better to ask developer to fix  his theme.

Answer (score 0):

***Fix OC 3.x Extension Installer***

OC 3 is limitating allowed folders to write when installing an extension, but some do require to put files elsewhere than pre-defined directories.

This extension fixes this issue by allowing the modules files to install anywhere.

If you get the message “The directory xxx is not allowed to be written to!” this extension is for you.

Please try this extension:
[Fix OC 3.x Extension Installer](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=33410&filter_category_id=5&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=56&sort=date_added)

Comment: There is absolutely no need for such "hacks"!
Why?
The limitations introduced with openCart v.3.x are enough to install everything.
So, if an extension or theme needs additional folders, their developer should fix that - because they are only lazy!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to navigate to the file system/custom.ocmod.xml and right click and click on properties, then uncheck readonly

[image: screenshot]
then click on apply or Ok  and it should work fine with you.